# Changing slider size on a gtk scale

Tags: css, c, linux, gtk

I want to change the slider of a Gtk scale in a Linux c program to show an image.
I'm using a CSS file to set the background image.
the image is showing, but the problem is that the slider is too small to show the image completely.

I tried using min-width and min-height in the CSS file, but it does not seem to work.

Here is the CSS that I used. The border-radius and background-image work, but the min-width and min-height do nothing.

```
.scale .slider{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: url("fader.png");
}
```

Edit: Here is the C code that applies the css style to the gtk elements:

```
...
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider, "gtktut01.css", NULL);
GtkStyleContext *context;
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(window));
gtk_style_context_add_provider    (context,GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(scale));
gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(window));
gtk_main ();
...
```

The window and scale are created using glade.

Comment: It'd be better if you could post the associated HTML too. However, give `background-size: cover` a try - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values

Comment: Hi, There is no HTML. It is a C program that uses GTK+. I edited my post to include the important bits of C code.

Comment: I tried the background-size, but that did not do the trick. The problem is not the size of the image, but the size of the slider handle. This is too small, so only a portion of the image is displayed. I can off course adjust the image size, but the slider handle is too small to see it propperly.

Comment: Even though the program is based on C that uses GTK+, there has to be certain HTML for the CSS to apply to, right?

Comment: No, there is no HTML. The CSS gets applied by the GTK+ system. It is a standalone gui program that runs on Linux, not in a web browser. The CSS gets applied on other parts of the program e.g. the main window background color, also the border radius on the slider can be adjusted just fine. Only the size gets somehow overruled.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but only someone with an experience working with GTK+ can help you out here

Comment: The best I've been able to do is using `background-size: 10px 10px;` or whatever you want the `fader.png` size to be. I have not been able to change the size of the actual slider knob, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I commented I couldn't change the size of the knob earlier. Well, I just did. If this is not what you're asking please be more specific.  Here's what I did:

[image: big slider knob with resized image]

Here's my `fader.png` I made in paint:

[image]

Here's a MWE for `main.c`:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>                                                                                

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)                                       
{                                                                                                   
    GtkWidget *window;                                                                              
    GtkWidget *box;                                                                                 
    GtkWidget *scale;                                                                               
    GtkStyleContext *context;                                                                       
    GtkCssProvider *provider;                                                                       

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);                                                       
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");                                             
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);                                      
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 100);                                      

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);                                                
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);                                                  

    scale = gtk_scale_new_with_range(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 5);                        
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), scale);                                                   

    provider = gtk_css_provider_new();                                                              
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(provider, "mystyle.css", NULL);                                 

    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(window));                                     
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(GTK_WIDGET(scale));                                      
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);                                                                    
}                                                                                                   

int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                     
{                                                                                                   
    GtkApplication *app;                                                                            
    int status;                                                                                     

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);                         
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);                                  
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);                                     
    g_object_unref(app);                                                                            

    return status;                                                                                  
}
```

And here's `mystyle.css`:

```css
scale slider {                                                                                      
    background-image: -gtk-scaled(url("fader.png"));                                                
    background-size: 100px 100px;                                                                   
    min-width: 100px;                                                                               
    min-height: 100px;                                                                              
}
```

Comment: I just tried your answer at home and it works!
I think I got the wrong version of GTK before. I was trying it on a computer at work. I'm not sure it got GTK 3 installed. Anyway I tried it now and it is just what iI was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, but want to do it in CSS only. I solve it with this CSS for my project that uses .glade gtk and python

```
scale slider{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 150px;  
}
```

or below for single gtkslider with id of sliderID

```
scale#sliderID slider{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: my answer does go over the issue at hand. the `min-width` and `min-height` is the specific way to resize as far as the issue to start it is because of the 2 '.' in the css file `.scale .slider{` should be `scale slider{` as far as the only difference in what I'm doing is using a glade file instead of coding gtk object in python

Comment: OK, my bad, I misinterpreted your answer as asking another question.

Comment: oh ok cool. Are you look for something in particular or just browsing